# Type function not subscriptable in Python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x

So every time I run the code it comes up with this message.I am running Python 3.5 btw. The aim of the program is to able to enter the username and password provided and if the user fails to input the correct username and password Username_Submit() will say you have 2 amount of guesses if it's the first try. At the moment the problem lies in Username_Name. Username_Name's purpose is to ask the user to input the correct username then ask whether they are sure if they are not they can change it. The same happens for the password then Username_Submit checks to see if it matches the correct username and password if so a message will say they may enter. If there is anything I need to explain, I can do so but the comments in the actual program should be clear enough.

```
Hello, your username is: Greg232 
Your password is: userword657
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Computing\Term 3\Username and Password.py", line 62, in <module>
    intro()
  File "F:\Computing\Term 3\Username and Password.py", line 8, in intro
    Username_verify()
  File "F:\Computing\Term 3\Username and Password.py", line 12, in Username_verify
    proceed = Username_Submit(name)
  File "F:\Computing\Term 3\Username and Password.py", line 36, in Username_Submit
    print(name[0], name[1])
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
>>> 



import time


def intro(): #Username and Password is displayed
    print("Hello, your username is: Greg232 ")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Your password is: userword657")
    Username_verify()

def Username_verify():
    name = Username_Name
    proceed = Username_Submit(name)
    print(proceed)


def Username_Name(): #User must input the correct username and password given to them
    username = input('Username: ')   
    double_check = input('Are you sure? ')
    if double_check == 'no':
          username     
    if double_check == 'yes':
            print('Proceed...')

    password = input("Password: ")
    double_check = input('Are you sure? ')
    if double_check == 'no':
        print("ok")
    if double_check == 'yes':
        Username_Submit()




def Username_Submit(name):
    attempt = 0 
    print(name[0], name[1])
    Submit == ''
    input("Submit?") #Double checks that the user is ok with what they entered
    if Submit == 'yes':
         if name[0] == 'Greg232' and name[1] == 'userword657':
             Username_Correct()
         while password != "userword657" and attempt <= 3:
             attempt = attempt + 1 #Username or/and password is not correct, they have 2 more attempts
             print("Your username or password is wrong.")
             print("You have 2 more attempts left. ")
             print("You have entered 3 attempts and you are locked out,")
             print("contact the network office.")
    else:
         Username_Name()







def Username_Correct(): #User inputs correct username and password, therefore, can enter the system
    print("You may enter the system.")



intro()
Username_Submit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget function call in `Username_verify()`. Correct it:

```
def Username_verify():
    name = Username_Name() # <-------!!!!!
    proceed = Username_Submit(name)
    print(proceed)
```

Comment: As in replace name = Username_Name() with name = Username_verify() ?

Comment: I tried this and came with a recursion error: File "F:\Computing\Term 3\Username and Password.py", line 11, in Username_verify
    name = Username_verify()
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Comment: I mean you should just add parenthesis. I don't mean replace something. If you have recursion error - you have some error in your program logic. Try to execute it step by step on the paper. Your code is extremely unreadable. It is very bad practice to end function with another function call instead of return of desired result. Try to rewrite code to clarify its logic.

Comment: I just realised what you meant HAHAHA what a silly mistake by me.